# How to represent a "must have" OWL restriction in Protege?

Tags: constraints, rdf, owl, protege, quantifiers

I am trying to build an ontology using OWL. I have two classes: `Test` and `Question`. I have an object property `hasQuestion` with Domain (`Test`) and Range (`Question`).

If I created an individual `Exam1` for the class `Test` and did not relate it to `Question` individual, I would like the reasoner to raise inconsistency. How can I do this in Protege?

For example:

```
Exam1 (Test)
Exam2 (Test) hasQuestion Quest1 (Question)
```

When I run the reasoner on `Exam1`, I should get an inconsistency since there are no questions related to it. However, `Exam2` should not give an inconsistency since it has `Quest1` related to it.

Comment: Please read about Open World Assumption in OWL. What you really need is a constraint language (SHACL, Pellet ICV, etc.) which OWL is not unfortunately

Comment: Also asked [here](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/protege-user/2019-March/009935.html) on the Protege mailing list. It would be nice to always mention this and refer to the mailing list thread, just for future reference.

Comment: Thank you. I recently found out about SHACL, however, I am yet to find an editor for SHACL.